# Why is this PHP call to json_encode silently failing - inability to handle single quotes?

Tags: php, json

I have a `stdClass` object called `$post` that, when dumped via `print_r()`, returns the following:

```
stdClass Object (
    [ID] => 12981
    [post_title] => Alumnus' Dinner Coming Soon
    [post_parent] => 0
    [post_date] => 2012-01-31 12:00:51
)
```

Echoing the result from calling `json_encode()` on this object results in the following:

```
{
    "ID": "12981",
    "post_title": null,
    "post_parent": "0",
    "post_date": "2012-01-31 12:00:51"
}
```

I'm assuming that something with the single quote is causing `json_encode` to choke, but I don't know what format is needed to escape that. Any ideas?

EDIT: Fixed mismatch in code examples. I'm running PHP version 5.3.8

EDIT2: Directly after encoding the object, I did this:

```
echo json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_UTF8;
```

This printed `1`, which means that the following error occurred: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded". [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

EDIT3: Calling `utf8_decode()` on the post title resulted in the following: "Alumnus? Dinner  Coming Soon". This data is being pulled from a MySQL database - the post title in particular is a text field, UTF-8 encoded. Maybe this single-quote is improperly encoded? The thing is, I have a SQL GUI app, and it appears correctly in that.

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/39Bmy6)... What PHP version are you running? And I note that the dumped object and the `json_encode()` result don't match (the `ID` is different) - verify that your code examples are correct.

Comment: It works for me as well. When you set the post_title are you surrounding it in double quotes ("")?

Comment: Show me a hex dump of that string.

Comment: 416c756d6e7573922044696e6e657220436f6d696e6720536f6f6e

Comment: @JimD The object is being pulled from a MySQL database, and the `post_title` field is a UTF-8 text field.

Comment: Is that single quote a simple, from-the-keyboard, single quote, or one of the alternate (sometimes tilted) single quotes that rich text apps like to automatically replace simple single quotes with?

Comment: Did you check your mysql connection charset ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: @Umbrella This is a title pulled from a WordPress post, so it has almost certainly been altered by a rich text editor.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to set the connection encoding before executing queries. How this is done depends on the API you are using to connect:

- call `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` if you use the [old, deprecated API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).
- call `mysqli_set_charset("utf8")` if you use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- add the [`charset` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) to the connection string if you use PDO and PHP >= 5.3.6. In earlier versions you need to execute `SET NAMES utf8`.

When you obtain data from MySQL any text will be encoded in "client encoding", which is likely [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) if you don't configure it otherwise. The character that is causing your problem is the "curly quote", seen as `92` in the hex dump, which confirms that the mysql client is encoding text in windows-1252.

Another thing you might consider is pass all text through `utf8_encode`, but in this case it wouldn't produce the correct result. PHP's `utf8_encode` converts **iso-8859-1**-encoded text. In this encoding \x92 is a non-printable control character, which would be converted into a non-printable control character in utf-8. You could use `str_replace("\x92", "'", $input)` to fix the problem for this particular character, but if there's any chance there will be any other non-ascii characters in the database you'll want to have the client use UTF-8.

Comment: Or the equivalent mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8") if you're using those.

Comment: Doctrine DBAL uses the `charset` [option](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) which you can set to "utf8" to fix this as well.

Comment: mysql_ and mysqli_ functions are deprecated, we use PDO now

Comment: @MarcoMarsala fixed. mysqli is not deprecated btw

Comment: Be on the lookout for `utf8mb4` for some reason there are two version in MySQL so using `uft8` might help.

Comment: Good one helps a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

What I've had to do in the past to json_encode on text with utf8 characters is

```
json_encode( utf8_encode( $s ) );
```

and in some cases

```
json_encode( htmlspecialchars( utf8_encode( $s ) ) );
```

the utf8_encode() to handle special characters (note, that's Encode, not Decode)

the htmlspecialchars() depending on how you mean to use the JSON string, you may be able to leave this out

and finally, json_encode() to get your JSON packet.

Since you want to json_encode an object, you would need to call utf8_encode() on each text part first, or write a simple recursive utf8_encode().  For your example case, this would do:

```
function myEncode($o) {
    $o->title = utf8_encode($o->title);
    return json_encode($o);
}
```

Comment: and if $s is an array?

Comment: Then, I suppose one would have to do something like `array_walk_recursive($s, 'utf8_encode');`

Comment: @Umbrella Just an FYI that snippet will just set $s to true. I believe you're thinking of array_map, unfortunately it doesn't have a recursive mode.

Comment: for me `json_encode( utf8_encode( $s ) );` it's enough. Thank's

Answer (score 10):

I would like to refer you about this issue, 
on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199017/how-to-solve-json-error-utf8-error-in-php-json-decode)
I suggest you use a json_encode wrapper like this :

```
function safe_json_encode($value){
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0) {
        $encoded = json_encode($value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        $encoded = json_encode($value);
    }
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $encoded;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            return 'Maximum stack depth exceeded'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            return 'Underflow or the modes mismatch'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            return 'Unexpected control character found';
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            return 'Syntax error, malformed JSON'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $clean = utf8ize($value);
            return safe_json_encode($clean);
        default:
            return 'Unknown error'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
    }
}


function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

And after define these function you can use it direct,

```
echo safe_json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 7):

i was having the same issue while JSON encoding a php array from an ODBC query results,  my Server's OBC is configured with 'en_US.819', is a production server so there is no way i can even touch that!!.

when i tried:

```
echo json_encode($GLOBALS['response'], true);
```

Where 'respose' is an array with the results, it works as intended as long no bizarre char is present, if so, json_encode fails returning empty.

The solution?.... UTF encode results while fetching the rows from query:

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql_query);
$response = array();
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) { 
     $json['pers_identificador'] = $row['pers_identificador'];
     $json['nombre_persona'] = utf8_encode( $row['nombre_persona'] );
     $json['nombre_1'] = utf8_encode($row['nombre_1'] );
     $json['nombre_2'] = utf8_encode($row['nombre_2'] );
     array_push($response, $json); 
  }
```

Now json_encode works!!!, the resulting string is something like this:

```
{"page_id":300,"max_rows":"100","cant_rows":"12897","datos":
  [{"pers_identificador":"301","cedula":"15250068","interno_1":"178202","interno_2":"","nombre_persona":"JOSE JUAN PANDOLFO ZAGORODKO","nombre_1":"JOSE","nombre_2":"JUAN",....
```

That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the charset in the database config:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'driver_options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
)
```