# How to solve JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error in php json_decode?

Tags: php, json, parsing, jsonp

I am trying this code

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/alerts/preview?q=test&t=7&f=1&l=0&e");
print_r(json_decode(utf8_encode($json), true));

        //////////////

// Define the errors.
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$json_errors = array();
foreach ($constants["json"] as $name => $value) {
    if (!strncmp($name, "JSON_ERROR_", 11)) {
        $json_errors[$value] = $name;
    }
}

// Show the errors for different depths.
foreach (range(4, 3, -1) as $depth) {
    var_dump(json_decode($json, true, $depth));
    echo 'Last error: ', $json_errors[json_last_error()], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
}
```

I've tried a lot of functions, html_entities_decode, utf8_encode and decode, decoding the hex codes, but I always get the error "JSON_ERROR_UTF8".

**How could I solve this?**

Comment: I am not sure why the error is coming out as a UTF8 error.  The JSON being returned by that URL is not valid as it uses single quotes where it should use doubles. It does not pass JSON LINT (http://jsonlint.com/). That said, I assume `$x` on line 2 of your code should be `$json`?

Comment: Yes i was cleaning out the code and forgot to change $x, have you tried making it valid and then trying to decode it? I wouldn't know how to make it valid.

Comment: I have tried replacing all single quotes with doubles, but then run into other validation issues. Still taking a look.

Comment: I've end up using regex, couldn't get the json working.

Answer (score 79):

[There is a good function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#115980)  to sanitize your arrays.

I suggest you use a json_encode wrapper like this :

```
function safe_json_encode($value, $options = 0, $depth = 512, $utfErrorFlag = false) {
    $encoded = json_encode($value, $options, $depth);
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $encoded;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            return 'Maximum stack depth exceeded'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            return 'Underflow or the modes mismatch'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            return 'Unexpected control character found';
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            return 'Syntax error, malformed JSON'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $clean = utf8ize($value);
            if ($utfErrorFlag) {
                return 'UTF8 encoding error'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
            }
            return safe_json_encode($clean, $options, $depth, true);
        default:
            return 'Unknown error'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()

    }
}

function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

In my application utf8_encode() works better than iconv()

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: This caused a nasty memory spike in my code after a couple of months. It worked in 99.99% times, though.

Comment: You saved me 1h. Thx !

Comment: You are the god of json

Comment: This fixed a bunch of broken encodings for me - appreciate it!

Comment: @SteveB I assume your memory loop is due to the fact that this function can get into a recursive loop since it calls itself. If it continues to receive error  JSON_ERROR_UTF8 it'll get stuck. I added a fourth param that allows the JSON_ERROR_UTF8 case to call itself if that param is true but I pass in false to the call to itself that way if it fails again it won't continue to call itself. It'll prevent an infinite loop, or even just a high memory loop. The downside is you're only allowed "one try" but per my coding style that is all you should need, else I want to be notified of the error.

Comment: @SteveB I think it's a great idea. Feel free to edit the post

Comment: Konstantin you probably meant @Travis :) I've applied his comment and submitted edit though. Reversed the logic because it felt more "obvious" without negations.

Comment: @Travis @ Travis indeed :)

Comment: Despite it's name, utf8_encode is not some kind of "fix all my UTF-8 problems" function. It simply converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. Running it on a string which is not, in fact, in ISO-8859-1 encoding, will give you "valid" but completely nonsensical UTF-8.

Answer (score 55):

You need simple line of code:

```
$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($input));
$json = json_decode($input);
```

Credit: Sang Le, my teamate gave me this code. Yeah!

Comment: Doesn't work for me `PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in /tmp/parse_json.php on line 4`. And returns false

Comment: `Warning: iconv(): Wrong encoding, conversion from "UTF-8" to "UTF-8//IGNORE" is not allowed` return **false** PHP 8.0.0

Comment: This code is mumbo-jumbo, which does not "fix" UTF-8. Despite it's name, utf8_encode is **not** some kind of "fix all my UTF-8 problems" function. It simply converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 - which if you have iconv available, can be more clearly written as  `iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $input)`. Running it on a string which is not, in fact, in ISO-8859-1 encoding, will give you "valid" but completely nonsensical UTF-8. The following call to iconv will do absolutely nothing, because the output of utf8_encode will **always** be valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 13):

The iconv function is pretty worthless unless you can guarantee the input is valid.  Use mb_convert_encoding instead.

```
mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "auto");
```

You can get more explicit than "auto", and even specify a comma-separated list of expected input encodings.

Most importantly, invalid characters will be handled without causing the entire string to be discarded (unlike iconv).

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic bullet which will "solve" encoding problems; you have to understand what encoding you have, and then convert it.

Computers ultimately transmit and store binary data; to make that binary data useful, we devise codes that say "this string of binary represents an 'a', that one represents a 'b', and this other one represents the man-in-business-suit-levitating emoji ️". UTF-8 (simplifying a little bit) is just one of those encodings. Others have names like ASCII, ISO-8859-1, Windows Code Page 1252, and Shift-JIS.

If all you know is that a string is "not UTF-8" *you cannot make it into UTF-8* because you don't know if the first character is supposed to be an "a", or a "️".

If you *do* know what encoding your string is in, you can use any of three functions in PHP; depending on your installation of PHP, some or all might be unavailable, but they are what you want.

- [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)
- [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
- [UConverter::transcode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/uconverter.transcode.php)

Note that mb_convert_encoding lets you leave out the argument that states the current encoding. This does **not** automatically work out the correct encoding, it just uses a global setting which you control.

There are two other functions provided in PHP which are badly named: [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [utf8_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php). These are just extremely limited versions of the three functions above: they *can only convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 and back*. If your string is not in that encoding (and you don't want it to be) *these functions will not help you*. They might make your errors go away, but that's not the same as fixing your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Decoding JSON in PHP**
Decoding JSON is as simple as encoding it. PHP provides you a handy json_decode function that handles everything for you. If you just pass a valid JSON string into the method, you get an object of type stdClass back. Here’s a short example:

```
<?php
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "cool": "attr"}';
$result = json_decode($string);

// Result: object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" ["cool"]=> string(4) "attr" }
var_dump($result);

// Prints "bar"
echo $result->foo;

// Prints "attr"
echo $result->cool;
?>
```

If you want to get an associative array back instead, set the second parameter to true:

```
<?php
$string = '{"foo": "bar", "cool": "attr"}';
$result = json_decode($string, true);

// Result: array(2) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" ["cool"]=> string(4) "attr" }
var_dump($result);

// Prints "bar"
echo $result['foo'];

// Prints "attr"
echo $result['cool'];
?>
```

If you expect a very large nested JSON document, you can limit the recursion depth to a certain level. The function will return null and stops parsing if the document is deeper than the given depth.

```
<?php
$string = '{"foo": {"bar": {"cool": "value"}}}';
$result = json_decode($string, true, 2);

// Result: null
var_dump($result);
?>
```

The last argument works the same as in json_encode, but there is only one bitmask supported currently (which allows you to convert bigints to strings and is only available from PHP 5.4 upwards).We’ve been working with valid JSON strings until now (aside fromt the null depth error). The next part shows you how to deal with errors.

**Error-Handling and Testing**
If the JSON value could not be parsed or a nesting level deeper than the given (or default) depth is found, NULL is returned from json_decode. This means that no exception is raised by json_encode/json_deocde directly.

So how can we identify the cause of the error? The json_last_error function helps here. json_last_error returns an integer error code that can be one of the following constants (taken from here):

JSON_ERROR_NONE: No error has occurred.
JSON_ERROR_DEPTH: The maximum stack depth has been exceeded.
JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH: Invalid or malformed JSON.
JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded.
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX: Syntax error.
JSON_ERROR_UTF8: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded (since PHP 5.3.3).
With those information at hand, we can write a quick parsing helper method that raises a descriptive exception when an error is found.

```
<?php
class JsonHandler {

    protected static $_messages = array(
        JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
        JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
        JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'Invalid or malformed JSON',
        JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
        JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
        JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
    );

    public static function encode($value, $options = 0) {
        $result = json_encode($value, $options);

        if($result)  {
            return $result;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(static::$_messages[json_last_error()]);
    }

    public static function decode($json, $assoc = false) {
        $result = json_decode($json, $assoc);

        if($result) {
            return $result;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(static::$_messages[json_last_error()]);
    }

}
?>
```

We can now use the exception testing function from the last post about exception handling to test if our exception works correctly.

```
// Returns "Correctly thrown"
assertException("Syntax error", function() {
    $string = '{"foo": {"bar": {"cool": NONUMBER}}}';
    $result = JsonHandler::decode($string);
});
```

Note that since PHP 5.3.3, there is a JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error returned when an invalid UTF-8 character is found in the string. This is a strong indication that a different charset than UTF-8 is used. If the incoming string is not under your control, you can use the utf8_encode function to convert it into utf8.

```
<?php echo utf8_encode(json_encode($payload)); ?>
```

I’ve been using this in the past to convert data loaded from a legacy MSSQL database that didn’t use UTF-8.

[source](https://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/)

Answer (score -2):

I solved adding another 'if' to manage objects in the 'utf8ize' function by @Konstantin (I've not used the other function) :

```
function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    } else if (is_object($mixed)) {
        $a = (array)$mixed; // from object to array
        return utf8ize($a);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```