# Php breaks when seting class array key from mysql view result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

So I was as normal fetching results from my MYSQL database using PDO from a view table I created, all is fine with var_dump and print_r UNTIL I try to set the result to any array key.

```
public function getBag($user = false)
{
    $id = ($user) ? $user['id'] : $_SESSION['user']['id'];

    $bag = $this->prepareFromArray('bag', array('user_id' => $id), 'select', 'all', array('user_id'));

    $result = (isset($bag[0]['id'])) ? $bag : null;

    return $result;
}

public function prepPlayer($user)
{
    $user['medals'] = $this->getmedals($user);
    $user['pokemons'] = $this->getPokemons($user);
    $user['bag'] = $this->getBag($user);

    for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) { 
        $user['pokemons']['roster'][$i] = (isset($user['pokemons']['roster'][$i])) ? $user['pokemons']['roster'][$i] : ['name' => "None", "level" => 0, "wild_id" => 0, "color" => 0];
    }

    $trainerClass = strtolower(trim($user['class']));

    $cover = "img/Trainers/$trainerClass/background/{$user['wallpaper']}.png";

    $user['cover'] = (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$cover")) ? $cover : "img/Trainers/backgrounds/1.png";

    return $user;
}
```

I am using the prepPlayer method to prepare players when called upon, everything works fine UNTIL we get to getting the players bag.

if I comment out the db (prepareFromArray) method it will naturaly work, if I print_r the bag variable, it shows all items from the bag view, but once I try to return the result into the $user['bag'] array element all hell breaks lose, and the result is a blank page for my stream file that depends on this. I am using

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $user), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

to output the result to my angular service.

here is how my bag view looks like

```
CREATE VIEW `bag` AS
SELECT 
    `player_items`.`id` AS `id`,
    `players`.`id` AS `user_id`,
    `items`.`id` AS `item`,
    `items`.`qual` AS `qual`,
    `items`.`cat` AS `cat`,
    `items`.`name` AS `name`,
    `items`.`description` AS `description`,
    `items`.`chance` AS `chance`,
    `items`.`cost` AS `cost`,
    `items`.`trade` AS `trade`,
    `player_items`.`amount` AS `amount`,
    `player_items`.`cap` AS `cap`,
    `player_items`.`sell` AS `sell`,
    `items`.`temp` AS `temp`
FROM
    ((`players`
    JOIN `items`)
    JOIN `player_items`)
WHERE
    ((`players`.`id` = `player_items`.`user_id`)
        AND (`player_items`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`))
ORDER BY `player_items`.`id`
```

Comment: Is it ok that you use `$user` as a parameter and rewriting it in your `prepPlauer` function?

Comment: Using it as a parameter gives me access to it as if I declared it in the code block, although In this case $userClass->getBag() I can call without prepPlayer and it would still break.

Comment: After looking what you mean @u_mulder they $user passed in to the methods, are only used to find out any user info I need, what is returned form the methods are array objects of what I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that ever has this issue, you need to first check UTF8 errors of a JSON encode call, like so.

from: [How to solve JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error in php json_decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199017/how-to-solve-json-error-utf8-error-in-php-json-decode)

```
function safe_json_encode($value){
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0) {
        $encoded = json_encode($value, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        $encoded = json_encode($value, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $encoded;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            return 'Maximum stack depth exceeded'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            return 'Underflow or the modes mismatch'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            return 'Unexpected control character found';
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            return 'Syntax error, malformed JSON'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $clean = utf8ize($value);
            return safe_json_encode($clean);
        default:
            return 'Unknown error'; // or trigger_error() or throw new Exception()

    }
}

function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

If you don't do this, you will receive a blank page when ever the array you are encoding a utf8 error.