# Why does json_encode return empty?

Tags: php, json, ajax, is-empty, jsonresult

I have a problem with my script which request records from database by AJAX, and then return it back via JSON. It works normally on my localhost but when I upload it to server it's doesn't work.

I read topics about empty `json_encode()` result, and found that similar problem was for many people and there was solution with data encoding. But all my files, tables, and data normally in UTF-8 encoding both locally and on the remote server.

All what do my PHP script is request records from database (I use PDO library, and set database encoding to UTF-8 - `SET NAMES 'utf8'`) then throw the loop it generates HTML tags with data from database and then return back as array with `json_encode($result)`.

If I'll try to `print_r($result)` and watch them in browser `Developer tools` I will see correct array with normall data. But if I'll return them with `json_encode($result)` the result will be nothing.

Also I have Russian text in my result array.

**Example of results array:**

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="1">
                [1] => 1
                [2] => Английский стол
                [3] => <span title='Вращающийся английский стол с выдвижными ящиками.Англия, 1900-е гг.Красное дерево, мягкая кожа диска, передвигается на бронзовых колесиках.Диаметр 91, высота 71 см.'>Вращающийся английский стол с выдвижными ящиками.<br>Англия, 1900-е гг.<br>Красное дерево, мягкая кожа диска, перед...</span>
                [4] => 250&euro;
                [5] => sss
                [6] => 
                [7] => <span class="label label-sm label-success">Опубликован</span>
                [8] => <a href="/jc_adm/?p=edit_product&id=1" class="btn btn-xs default btn-editable"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Редактировать</a>
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="2">
                [1] => 2
                [2] => Старинный раскладной стол
                [3] => <span title='Оригинальный стол 1800 г. вторая половина.Изогнутые ножки, резная опора, натуральное дерево.Высота 125 Ширина 56 Высота 78 см.'>Оригинальный стол 1800 г. вторая половина.<br>Изогнутые ножки, резная опора, натуральное дерево.<br>Высота 125 Ширин...</span>
                [4] => 210&euro;
                [5] => sss
                [6] => 
                [7] => <span class="label label-sm label-success">Опубликован</span>
                [8] => <a href="/jc_adm/?p=edit_product&id=2" class="btn btn-xs default btn-editable"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Редактировать</a>
            )

        [2] => Array......
```

But if I manualy create array with, for example next infromation
`echo json_encode(array('fruits' => array('banan', 'apple', 'mango', 'редиска')));`.

It will work correctly, and will show normally JSON encoded string. But my array from example does not want to return. Why is this happening?

I found that if I remove setting database encoding `$objDB->query("SET NAMES utf8");`, I will get result but instead of russian text I get question marks `?????`

```
{"data":[["<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"1\">",1,"?????????? ????","<span title='??????????? ?????????? ???? ? ?????????? ???????.??????, 1900-? ??.??????? ??????...
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, it will definitely works

```
function utf8ize($d) {
  if (is_array($d)) {
     foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
       $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
     }
  } else if (is_string ($d)) {
     return utf8_encode($d);
  }
   return $d;
}
```

and then call

```
echo json_encode( utf8ize( $array ) );
```

Comment: Yes this works fine, but the reason why we need to hardcode this function is obscure however. PHP developers should embed this option in the command's parameters!

Answer (score 3):

Your json_encode seems to be failing, you would have gotten the notice if you had it enabled in your PHP config. There is other way of deciding is your json_encode failed, try getting the value of [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

This error message might be helpful to decide what went wrong with the encoding.

**EDIT**

Questions like this has already been answered:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26760943/1621713)

Comment: Hello, Arun!
It's return to me `int 5`, and the same return on localhost. But on localhost it's works in contrast with remote server. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Check 2nd parameter of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Hello, Jigar!
Yeah, i tryed to do that, but result is same. :(