# PHP json_encode doesn't print anything

Tags: php, mysql, json, php-5.3

I'm running `PHP` and `MySQL` and have the following code:

```
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query($search_query);
if ($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
        //var_dump($data);
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
      echo 'empty';
    }
}
```

If my query has no rows I do get `empty` returned.
But if there's any records I get a `Resource has no content` in Safari.

**But** if I uncomment my `//var_dump($data);` then I do get a nice array of values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php JSON\_encode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972084/php-json-encode-not-working)

Comment: Take a look at your out of date `mysql_` functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: What does `json_last_error()` say?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: ` $res = array_map('utf8_encode', $res); ` sovled it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Database connection.
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db_name');

// Your query.
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM yuor_table";

$data = array();
$result = $mysqli->query($search_query);
if ($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
        //var_dump($data);
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
      echo 'empty';
    }
}
```

This is very simple solution. I would suggest to use "mysqli".

Comment: Why will this fix the problem?  Seems the OP has no problem fetching rows.

Comment: @Progrock I suppose that the real problem is not procedural style but wrong use of "mysql" function during connection or database selection. Anyway, "mysqli" extension is much more indicated than deprecated "mysql".

Comment: But the issue here looks to be the json encoding.  Not necessarily their database connection.