# Can't make a json_encode on a sql result in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following mysql request in my php file:

```
 $command = "SELECT weapon_id, weapon_name, weapon_dammage, weapon_munitions FROM weapon;";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $command);
 $rows = array();

 while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows[] = array(
         'weapon_id' => $r['weapon_id'],
         'weapon_name' => $r['weapon_name'],
         'weapon_dammage' => $r['weapon_dammage'],
         'weapon_munitions ' => $r['weapon_munitions ']
     );
 }

 echo json_encode($rows);
```

I don't understand why there is nothing returned (I have a blank page). My request is good (tested), and the same code works with anoter request (for example SELECT * FROM player).

Do you know what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: print_r($rows) and see if it returns something

Comment: Yes, print_r($rows) works and I have my array

Comment: Make sure you're not having any Fatal error for some reason. Is error reporting on? Also, try `var_dump(json_encode($rows));` instead of `echo`

Comment: @Rizwan var_dump returns 'boolean : false'

Comment: Does it throw any error ??? or warning

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI No, there is no error. Just a blank page, nothing else.. And var_dump returns 'boolean : false'

Comment: may be your array contains some quotes that's why?

Comment: Try to remove space and check.
 'weapon_munitions' => $r['weapon_munitions']

Comment: @LucasPierrat try [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);` on the top  and then excute

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I alrealy have errors activated..

Comment: If var_dump returns "boolean: false" as you say, then there's an error with the SQL query. Try running it in a console connection and see what happens.

Comment: Which os you are using ??

Comment: check json_last_error

Comment: @RayO'Donnell but when I copy/paste my request in PhpMyAdmin to test it, it works correctly..

Comment: json_last_error returns '5'. What does it mean ?

Comment: @RayO'Donnell No, it means the `json_encode` function couldn't work. Many PHP functions return `false` when they can't execute properly.

Comment: change this `$r['weapon_munitions ']`  for this `$r['weapon_munitions']`

Comment: @DaniloBustos I remove the blank space, it is not the problem..

Comment: json erro 5 means "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded".

Comment: @LucasPierrat Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17182431/1541016)

Comment: You need to make sure all charset are in utf-8

Comment: It was a utf8 error yes.. I changed it in my database and the problem is solved.. Thanks for helping me !

Comment: But my database is encoded in utf8. Why there was this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP 5.2.0 or higher ? If not, you will have to install the JSON module.

From http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default.

You can check your version using `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have PHP 5.6.25