# PHP array not converting to JSON using json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to convert my `$response` array to JSON but it is not converting. I tried to echo the values in the array to be sure that it is not null.

```
    if($row['count(*)']>0)
    {
        $sql="select * from guide_city_detail where CITY='$place'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $result1->fetch_assoc();
        $row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
        $response['status']=1;
        $response['city']=$row['CITY'];
        $response['state']=$row['STATE'];
        $response['country']=$row['COUNTRY'];
        $response['heads']=$row['HEADS'];
        $response['col1']=$row['COL1'];
        $response['col2']=$row['COL2'];
        $response['col3']=$row['COL3'];
        $response['col4']=$row['COL4'];
        $response['col5']=$row['COL5'];
        $response['col6']=$row['COL6'];
        $response['col7']=$row['COL7'];
        $response['col8']=$row['COL8'];
        $response['col9']=$row['COL9'];
        //echo $response['country'];
    }
    else
    {
        $response['status']=0;// save the entry for future references
        $output = shell_exec("java -cp \".;D:/letsgo/mysql.jar;D:/letsgo/jsoup.jar;\" GeneralPopulate $place 2>&1");
        //echo "$output";
    }
    $res=json_encode($response);
    echo $res;
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `$e = json_last_error();`?

Comment: The output of $e = json_last_error(); is 5

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php: `5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8`

Comment: In my system, `5` is `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`. You are not using UTF-8, are you?

Comment: Please see the updated question, I now converted to UTF-8 as suggested in the answer

Comment: Is this a confirmation that you are not using UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1? Whatever, `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` still means the same: not valid UTF-8.

Comment: How can I solve this now ?

Comment: Solved it by converting final array to utf-8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24414901/13508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-last-error.php) gives you the `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` error code (5), then you will have to encode your datas in UTF-8 :

**Need to convert final array to utf-8.**

```
<?php

$response = array_map('utf8_encode', $response);
```

Comment: still not getting the json string

Comment: Does the error code is the same ?

Comment: How could you possibly know that data is currently encoded as `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: Yes error code is same

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález because the `java -cp \".;D:/letsgo/mysql.jar;` shows the system working on Windows :p So I assume this is the old school ISO-8859-1 encoding

Comment: @Swarnveer what's the encoding of your PHP page ?

Comment: Do you mean Windows-1252?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think this is not the default format for Windows PHP files

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR ASCII

Comment: Checked that using echo mb_detect_encoding($str);

Comment: This is getting kind of surrealistic. There's no "default format", you can fire any editor and save anything in a file with ".php" extension. Neither `utf8_encode()` nor `mb_detect_encoding()` do what most people assume by name.

Comment: How can I solve the error now