# json_encode not working with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using MySQL to store a list of items on a database, and I am trying to retrieve all of the items from a single table. The connection part is working fine, and retrieving items seems to work well, but I cannot json_encode a list of items.

```
  // Executes SQL query on the database specified by $con
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM productlist";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(nl2br("\n Failed to execute query"));

  // Retrieves all the rows returned by the SQL query
  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
  }

  echo json_encode($rows[0]); // test whether retrieval works

  // Displays rows in content-type JSON and in PRETTY_PRINT
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here is the code. The `json_encode` of `rows[0]` works well. However, when I comment it out and try to do the same with `rows`, it just returns nothing.

It's not even returning an error, it executes well, it's just that the `json_encode` function returns nothing at all when I try it with `rows`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After your test line, can you write `print_r($rows);` and paste what it prints – removing any sensitive information. Also, you can try using `echo json_last_error();` at the end to find out the error.

Comment: I think you are using `echo` before you set the header. This might cause problems.

Comment: remove `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: please post ajax call also

Comment: Removing the header, or using echo after the header instead still returns nothing apparently. Also, I'm not calling this with ajax, I'm loading the entire php file to see its output. It returns JSON with the single element, but nothing with the whole array though.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards the `print_r` command prints the contents of the database, and `json_last_error` returns 5. Guessing that's not good...

Comment: Now we are moving toward completing the question and making it on-topic.  We need all error codes and echoed checkpoints of working code.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, the problem seems to be with the syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/2943403

Comment: The content of $rows must be utf8 encoded.

Comment: @DanoelO we could not have given this advice earlier because the OP didn't give all of the vital info.  Now it can be closed with UTF-8 All the way through or similar.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10199017/2943403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't output something before setting a header. Unless you use output buffer (`ob_` functions):

```
ob_start();
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
ob_end_flush();
```

Or you could change the order in your script:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The last option might result in a JSON parse error since you output two 'objects' here.

The `json_last_error` [error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#106644) you mention is about UTF-8 encoding. You can try to utf8 encode and decode your json.

```
json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

If this does not solve the issue, you might want to [check if everything else is UTF-8 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1397220).

Answer (score 7):

Answering this question in case a poor soul with a similar problem finds this.
First of all, `print_r` and `json_last_error` proved to be insanely helpful in knowing what the problem was.

First of all, check the value that `json_last_error()` returns, and compare it with [the list of errors here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). If the number returned is `5`, try and check the values of the array by using the `print_r` function. If you see some weird characters, the probability is that the database has some wrong encoding.

In my case, changing certain columns from `latin` to `utf-8` fixed the problem.

Comment: Please show the sample text that causes the issue (as an edit on the question).  When you post a new question include errors before posting.

Comment: It's a huge wall of text, I can't exactly share it without it seeming incoherent.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the connection charset `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all I want to thank because I solved my "big" problem with this topic. I had a result of blank page, very hard to understand why.

How to detect:

```
echo json_encode($yourresult) ;
json_last_error($yourresult) ; 
// if the error is 5, it is UTF-8 issue
```

How to temporary correct with PHP 7.2:

```
echo json_encode($yourresult,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE); 
//wrong chars will be deleted
```

Comment: Why not use JSON exceptions? e.g. `json_encode($yourresult, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);`