# JS console throws an error while getting data with non english characters from db with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm writing simple web app (using MAMP for Mac for development). On the page there is  element with  that is being generated by this code:

**display_store_list.php**

```
include('db.php');

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM stores";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each option
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Some problem with getting values from DB</p>";
}
$conn->close();
```

There is with connection to database (id,store name, address, etc)
**db.php**

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**PROBLEM #1** It renders mostly correctly, but some store names has non-english caracters (ä, ö) and those are displayed as � symbols. Database, table and name all have **Collation** **utf8_unicode_ci** and values are displayed properly (with ä and ö)  in phpMyAdmin.
I did the research and only thing that worked was to include this to my **display_store_list.php**:

```
if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
}
```

No names with mentioned characters are rendered properly, **howere**, it doesnt solve problem number 2

**PROBLEM #2** I have js script that when user selects some store from the list, it loads (using jquery ajax and handlebars.js) other data related to selected store (address, phone number, etc).

```
var source   = $("#store-info").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$('#valitse').change(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).val();

    console.log(id);
    if(id == "") {
        return false;
    }
    //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as id in the GET
    else {
        $.ajax({url: 'store_info.php?q='+id,
              success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                //Parsing data to object
                var context = $.parseJSON(data);

                //Insterting received data to template
                $(".store_details").html(template(context));

              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
              }
        });
    }
});
```

It works as intended when user selects store **without** special characters (ä, ö) in it's name. When selecting store **with** these characters, js console fires:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input              localhost/:1

and script doesn't work. When user selects the store script logs to console log it's value and in both cases value has been got correctly.
Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATED**

**store_info.php**

```
    include('db.php');

$id = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql = " SELECT * FROM stores WHERE id = '".$id."' "; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Defining virables
        $name=$row['name'];
        $address=$row['address1'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $weekdays=$row['week'];
        $sat=$row['sat'];
        $sun=$row['sun'];
        $city=$row['city'];

        //Creating array
        $arrayStoreInfo = array(
            "Name" => $name,
            "Address" => $address, 
            "Phone" => $phone, 
            "Weekdays" => $weekdays,
            "Sat" => $sat,
            "Sun" => $sun,
            "City" => $city
        );

        //Send the array back to front end
        echo json_encode($arrayStoreInfo);

    }
} else {
    echo "Some problem with getting values related to that id from DB";
}   $conn->close();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Even though I have

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

in my header,

```
 <?php echo mb_detect_encoding($str); ?>
```

echoes ASCII on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As it turns out I didn't encode data from db the right way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098507/why-is-this-php-call-to-json-encode-silently-failing-inability-to-handle-singl)

Fellow stackoverflower actually answers my question. As it turns out, before quering anything from database one has to call `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` right after creating connection to db, **before** starting any queries.

In my case it was `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` right after

`$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

in my **db.php**.
No jason data is correct with non english characters and script executes as intended. Hope it might help someone.

**UPDATE** `echo json_last_error_msg();` after `jason_encode($array)` gave me the error every time I tried to pull data with non english characters "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded". Googling this, took me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098507/why-is-this-php-call-to-json-encode-silently-failing-inability-to-handle-singl) where solution was found.