# PHP: json_encode() doesn't show anything with multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a simple PHP script that fetches a table from my MySQL database and encodes the results in JSON, so I can use them later in Java.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost:3036";
    $username = "example_user";
    $password = "example_password";

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

    if(! $conn) {
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    mysql_select_db("database_name");
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if(! $retval) {
        die("Could not get data: " . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
        $output[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

This just gives a blank page as output (error messages are set to display).
However, if I change `json_encode($output)` to `json_encode($output[0])` (or any other number within the array's bounds), the output becomes that one `$row array`.

This is probably a really stupid question, but after about 3 hours of research I'm at my wit's end. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? `mysql_` functions do no longer exist. They've been deprecated for a few years and are now officially dead. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: Check the array variable by using print_r() or var_dump().

Comment: According to phpinfo(), I'm using v. 5.6.23-0+deb8u1. The MySQL part works fine, but I'll try changing it anyways, thanks.

Comment: Use json_last_error to check if there were errors in json_encode. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code (or a blank page) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to address before you go further because it's hard to code properly without the aid of error messages. The error reporting thumb rule is to show in development and log in production. As a starting point, I suggest you edit the system-wide `php.ini` file in the computer where you develop and tweak the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` directives ([details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508)).

Comment: This is what var_dump() returns: array(39) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["spanish"]=> string(8) "cirujano" ["german"]=> string(7) "Chirurg" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["spanish"]=> string(6) "recelo" ["german"]=> string(8) "Verdacht ... and so on

Comment: do var_dump(json_encode($output)); and paste output here.

Comment: As I said in my post, error messages are enabled. I confirmed that by making a syntax error and it showed up.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with encoding and special characters. Are both, your database and your file encoding using UTF-8?

Comment: This is the output of var_dump(json_encode($output));     Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/vocabulary.php on line 24
NULL

Comment: how is this possible you are using json_encode() and output shows json_decode() ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9098507/318758

Comment: I do have special characters in my database table. My file is definitely encoded in UTF-8. Unfortunately I don't know where to check if my database is as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got it to work. It was indeed a problem with the UTF-8 encoding. Using mysql_set_charset("utf8); resolved the problem. Thanks Joni, can I flag this as an answer or something? Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow...

Comment: @Sheogorath you can also create a new answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted. It'll be easier to find for other people with the same issue.

Comment: @MSpreij Thanks, I've added an answer, but I need to wait 2 days to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User @Joni led me to the solution.

Adding `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` fixed my issue.

As mentioned in this post: [Why is this PHP call to json_encode silently failing - inability to handle single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9098507/318758).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 echo json_encode($output) ;
```

Comment: That's what I first used until I found the print method in some tutorial. Same results with both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some utf8 character in your result set

add this statement before running your query

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Answer (score -1):

Update

```
"mysql"
```

to

```
"mysqli"
```

and add

```
mysqli_set_charset($variável_de _conexão, 'utf8');
```

below the connection variable