# Error trying to use json_encode() on an array() from mysqli fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm really having trouble trying to execute the function below:

```
function retrieve_as_JSON($sql_statement)
{
    $r = oquery($sqli); // oquery runs all that conn()->query() stuff
    if($r->num_rows)
    {
        $arr = array();
        while($tmp = $r->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
        {
            $arr[] = json_encode($tmp);
        }
        return json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

`$tmp` in the loop is:

```
Array ( [code] => ecb36c8e9e70b1622fb85ce1af7ba824 
        [prsn] => a6abd41ca4376f1ccb5d8425e9e97ca6 
        [type] => Isento 
        [motn] => Nome da Mãe 
        [natu] => Joseense 
        [nati] => Brasileiro 
        [mrts] => Solteiro(a) 
        [conj] => Nome da esposa 
        [prof] => Analista/Programador 
        [skcl] => Caucasiano/Branca 
        [lafr] => 0 )
```

The result is "[false]". Without the `json_encode()`, it return a regular array() filled with information. Using just one time the json encode function, on return or inside the while, it still gives nothing...

Any help?

Comment: You're double-json-encoding.  Remove the `json_encode($tmp)` and instead just make that `$arr[] = $tmp;`

Comment: What are the values of `$tmp`? Does your loop run?  Are you sure?  Your question is fairly unclear / confusing.

Comment: What is `$r` that you're attempting to use???

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @cale_b, i did this before (removing json_encode($tmp))... no success... still got ""... if I remove all json_encode() from this code it return the result as a normal php array() with data, so the loop is running...

Comment: OK, so what's the value of $tmp? It's impossible to help if you don't want to answer the questions that we ask in comments.

Comment: sorry... $tmp = Array
       (
            [code] => ecb36c8e9e70b1622fb85ce1af7ba824
            [prsn] => a6abd41ca4376f1ccb5d8425e9e97ca6
            [type] => Isento
            [motn] => Nome da Mãe
            [natu] => Joseense
            [nati] => Brasileiro
            [mrts] => Solteiro(a)
            [conj] => Nome da esposa
            [prof] => Analista/Programador
            [skcl] => Caucasiano/Branca
            [lafr] => 0
        )

Comment: @Don'tPanic, thanks but i doesn't work, the return result is ""...

Comment: @AbraCadaver question edited... $result wasn't in my code, it was $r...

Comment: Have you tried checking [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#refsect1-function.json-last-error-examples) to see why the `json_encode` fails?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"... do you know the meaning? utf8_encode didn't work....

Comment: [Check this out and see if it helps.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9099949/2734189)

Comment: @Don'tPanic great!!! worked.... thanks...